# Api 21 device taking theme from wrong folder

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-resources, android-theme

Am I not correct in saying if there is a 'values' folder and a 'values-v19' folder, then a lollipop device will go to the values-v19 folder automatically? This is not happening for me, I have the following (along with a few other settings) in values\themes.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

And a different color in values-v19\themes.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

My 5.0.1 Galaxy S4 is taking the color from values\themes.xml , is this the correct behaviour?

Edit: 
So [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) seem to agree:

> Now use this [values-v11] theme like you would any other, and your application will automatically switch to the holographic theme if running on Android 3.0 **or higher**.

There must be something preventing my device from accessing the values-19 folder but I have no idea what!

Comment: try with the folder `values-v21`

Comment: Haha just about to do that, I'm assuming it'll work but we'll see :)

Comment: Check it [What original docs said!!!](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html)

Comment: Yeah it v-21 works, but if v-21 does not exist then it should definitely use v-19 I would have thought....hmm that paragraph is interesting: **To avoid duplication of code, define your styles inside res/values/, modify the styles in res/values-v21/ for the new APIs, and use style inheritance, defining base styles in res/values/ and inheriting from those in res/values-v21/.** Maybe it's a problem because I am 'defining' it twice rather than using inheritance